# How can i hide content if not friend in Buddypress?

Tags: functions, templates, buddypress, front-end, conditional-tags

How can I hide some specific contents or div or other stuff depending on being friend or not in buddypress ??

I tried to use the `bp_is_user_friends()` function but it did not work !

Comment: "hide some specific contents or div or other stuff" is not very specific. Please add some more detail. Are you editing theme templates? Post the code you've tried, even if it didn't work.

Comment: yes i wanna show a div content if user who is watching my profile page is my friend if not so it wont be showed to him/her.

Comment: Welcome, @federico, please refer to this small guides: [About] and [ask]. . . .

Answer (score 1):

Returns true or false

```
friends_check_friendship( bp_loggedin_user_id(), bp_displayed_user_id() )
```